# How to find the rows that have exactly matching relationships in another table

Tags: sqlite, aggregate, relational-division

SQL beginner here, so bear with me please.

Let's say I have a simplified table `songs` looking like this

| id | title |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Villain |
| 2 | More |
| 3 | More (Laszlo Remix) |

I also have a table `songartists`:

| song_id | artist |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | K/DA |
| 2 | K/DA |
| 2 | Seraphine |
| 3 | K/DA |
| 3 | Seraphine |
| 3 | Laszlo |

Let's say I want to look for songs by `K/DA` and `Seraphine`, meaning no songs that only have one of the two artists and no songs that have those two plus other artists.

This is some code that technically does what I want, but is very slow:

```
SELECT title FROM songs WHERE
    EXISTS (SELECT * FROM songartists WHERE songartists.song_id == songs.id and songartists.artist == "K/DA")
    AND
    EXISTS (SELECT * FROM songartists WHERE songartists.song_id == songs.id and songartists.artist == "Seraphine")
    AND
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM songartists WHERE songartists.song_id == songs.id AND songartists.artist NOT IN ("K/DA","Seraphine"))
```

Obviously I can also do a very simple lookup for the title, then for the artists and programmatically compare. But is there a performant SQL solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by adding one inner join for each required artist and another join to exlude any other value other than the 2 desired ones. This third one is going to be a left join and a where condition expecting the song id to be null will be required (I'm assuming the songs table does not have null ids):

```
select s.*
from songs as s
inner join songartists as sa_k on sa_k.song_id = s.id and sa_k.artist = 'K/DA'
inner join songartists as sa_s on sa_s.song_id = s.id and sa_s.artist = 'Seraphine'
left join songartists as sa_others on sa_others.song_id = s.id and sa_others.artist not in ('K/DA', 'Seraphine')
where sa_others.song_id is null
```

Edit: I see you just edited your post.
This proposed solution, always providing that a proper index exists on songs.id and songartists.title will be optimal just needing 3 table searches for songartists and 1 for songs.

Answer (score 2):

**This is a pretty classic [*Relational Division Without Remainder*](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/t-sql-programming-sql-server/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/) question.**

I would suggest you start by placing the input list into a temporary table, so that you can refer to it in a set-based fashion, although you can also do this as a CTE. You may want to index it also.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE input AS
SELECT NULL AS artist WHERE 0
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES
  ('K/DA'),
  ('Seraphine')
) v;
```

Then there are a number of relational division solutions. One standard one is this

```
SELECT
  s.id,
  s.title
FROM songs s
JOIN songartists sa ON sa.song_id = s.id
LEFT JOIN input i ON i.artist = sa.artist
GROUP BY
  s.id,
  s.title
HAVING COUNT(*) = COUNT(i.artist)  -- no missing matches
   AND COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM input);  -- no extras
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=18c65426c099ed8c6b0b46f16a63e16a)

What this does is:

- Take all `song`s with their `songartist`s
- Left join the input list to it
- Group by the `song`
- Ensure that the number of rows (artists) is equal to the number of matches to the `input` (there are no rows which have no matches)
- And that the total number of rows is also equal to the total number of `input` rows (there are no extra rows)

Comment: Big benefit of using a temp table is that you are able to expand the number of different inputs to whatever you want, you are not limited by a fixed number of joins